# SQL MAX aggregate function not bringing the latest date

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

Purpose: I am trying to find the max date of when the teachers made a purchase and type.

Orders table

| ID | Ordertype | Status | TeacherID | PurchaseDate | SchoolID | TeacherassistantID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pencils | Completed | 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Paper | Completed | 1 | 3/5/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Notebooks | Completed | 1 | 4/1/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Erasers | Completed | 2 | 2/1/2021 | 2 | 2 |

Teachers table

| TeacherID | Teachername |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary Smith |
| 2 | Jason Crane |

School table

| ID | schoolname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC school |
| 2 | PS1 |
| 3 | PS2 |

Here is my attempted code:

```
SELECT o.ordertype, o.status, t.Teachername, s.schoolname
,MAX(o.Purchasedate) OVER (PARTITION by t.ID) last_purchase
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN teachers t ON t.ID=o.TeacherID
INNER JOIN schools s ON s.ID=o.schoolID
WHERE o.status in ('Completed','In-progress')
AND o.ordertype not like 'notebook'
```

It should look like this:

| Ordertype | Status | teachername | last_purchase | schoolname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paper | Completed | Mary Smith | 3/5/2021 | ABC School |
| Erasers | Completed | PS1 | 2/1/2021 | ABC school |

It is bringing multiple rows instead of just the latest purchase date and its associated rows. I think i need a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation functions are not appropriate for what you are trying to do.  Their purpose is to summarize values in multiple rows, not to choose a particular row.

Just a window function does not filter any rows.

You want to use window functions with filtering:

```
SELECT ordertype, status, Teachername, schoolname, Purchasedate
FROM (SELECT o.ordertype, o.status, t.Teachername, s.schoolname,
             o.Purchasedate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by t.ID ORDER BY o.PurchaseDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM orders o JOIN
           teachers t
           ON t.ID = o.TeacherID
           schools s
           ON s.ID = o.schoolID
      WHERE o.status in ('Completed', 'In-progress') AND
            o.ordertype not like 'notebook'
     ) o
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I’m looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in different way. it's better to use **Group By** for grouping the other columns and after that use **Order by** for reorder all records just like bellow.

```
SELECT top 1 o.ordertype, o.status, t.Teachername, s.schoolname
,o.Purchasedate 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN teachers t ON t.ID=o.TeacherID
INNER JOIN schools s ON s.ID=o.schoolID
having o.status in ('Completed','In-progress')
AND o.ordertype not like 'notebook'
group by o.ordertype, o.status, t.Teachername, s.schoolname
order by o.Purchasedate  Desc
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a different approach!